# Mysql php - how to deny image

Tags: php, mysql

how can we deny the image if the image does not correspond to a predetermined size image (using mysql php).

if users upload images and press the submit button, only the images that match the given size will be saved, but only if the picture does not match the size of the specified image will be denied

Comment: well..... *check the size, if it doesn't match, don't save the image?*

Answer (score 0):

In php you will get image size :

for uploaded image :

```
$image_info = getimagesize($_FILES["file_field_name"]["tmp_name"]);
$image_width = $image_info[0];
$image_height = $image_info[1];
```

or

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize('uploaded path of image');
echo "width: " . $width . "<br />";
echo "height: " .  $height;
```

Put your condition on image height,width for deny image upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function to achive this:

```
<?php
$predefined_width = "100";
$predefined_height = "150";
list($width, $height) = getimagesize("myimg.jpg");
$w = $width;
$h = $height;

// at the time of upload image just check this if condition:

if($w == $predefined_width && $h == $predefined_height) {
// image upload code
}

?>
```